# Error with beans.factory, JwtProvider & Jwt.secret

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jwt

Im having problems with my project in Java, making some Login with Jwt, below you can see the error thats throws me, really trying everything that see on the internet but nothing works for me.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'Jwt.secret' in value "${Jwt.secret}"
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'Jwt.secret' in value "${Jwt.secret}"
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'Jwt.secret' in value "${Jwt.secret}">

Here there is the JwtTokenFilter.java

public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

```
private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtProvider.class);

@Autowired
JwtProvider jwtProvider;
@Autowired
UserDetailsImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String token = getToken(request);
        if (token != null && jwtProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            String nombreUsuario = jwtProvider.getNombreUsuarioFromToken(token);
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(nombreUsuario);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                    null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }
    } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("Fallo el metodo doFilterInternal");
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private String getToken(HttpServletRequest request){
String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
if(header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer"))
       return header.replace("Bearer","");
  return null;
}
```

}`

MainSecurity.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MainSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Autowired
UserDetailsImpl userDetailsServicesImpl;
@Autowired
JwtEntryPoint jwtEntryPoint;

@Bean
public JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter(){
    return new JwtTokenFilter();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Override
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManager();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServicesImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

}`

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Where's your `Jwt.secret`?

Comment: Looks like in your `JwtProvider` you have something like `@Value("${Jwt.secret}")`, and something's wrong with the placeholder here. maybe you don't have this property or its name is incorrect, or you defined a static field which cannot be processed by Spring

Comment: It was a error in my application.properties where Jwt.secret and Jwt.expiration where misspelled, that resolved everything else. Thanks you so much for taking the time to help me.